# I don't know how to do this at ubuntu tensorflow-gpu, "E tensorflow / core / util / events_writer.cc: 104]

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I need to write a checkpoint on this deep learning problem. But that error is preventing me from writing the file. (E : at tf.summary.FileWriter)

Error : 
"tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.

i tryed this. Reinstallation, deletion, and authorization (tensorflow-gpu, tensorflow, tensorboard)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    dir = pickledir
    dic_0 = pat_level_arr(dir, 0, [0, 1])
    dic_1 = pat_level_arr(dir, 1, [1, 0])

    seed = 42
    abc = range(len(dic_0))
    abcd = range(len(dic_1))

    dic_0_train, dic_0_test, _, _ = train_test_split(
        dic_0, abc, test_size=0.244, random_state=seed)
    dic_1_train, dic_1_test, _, _ = train_test_split(
        dic_1, abcd, test_size=0.35, random_state=seed)

    dic_train = np.concatenate((dic_0_train, dic_1_train), axis=0)
    dic_test = np.concatenate((dic_0_test, dic_1_test), axis=0)
    summaries_dir = './logs_level'
#here is the problem "tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
======================================================================
    print("here is start\n")
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/train', sess.graph)
    test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/test')
    print("here is end\n")
======================================================================
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    # For train
    try:
        saver.restore(sess, './modelckpt/inception.ckpt')
        print('Model restored')
        epoch_saved = data_saved['var_epoch_saved'].eval()
    except tf.errors.NotFoundError:
        print('No saved model found')
        epoch_saved = 1
    except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError:
        print('Model structure has change. Rebuild model')
        epoch_saved = 1
```

E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.

ValueError : the passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: ./modelckpt/inception.ckpt

tensorflow-gpu version is 1.10.0.
python version is 3.5(i think).
I install tensorboard already.

Comment: never seen that before, have the folders already in your file system?

Comment: have you saved/created the checkpoint first before trying to restore?

Comment: The problem here is not the the writer, its the way you are loading the Tensorflow model. You can go through this tutotial through this basic tutorial and check if the steps you are following are complying with this tutorial. Also you can refer  refer to the following [answer] (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22443#issuecomment-451927881) and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the error conveys that the checkpoint file is absent and therefore it is not a valid checkpoint.

You need to **Save the Model** using the below code, **before executing `saver.restore()` method**  as it loads the file from the disk.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.

  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

Please refer Save and Restore explanation and Code for Tensorflow Version 1.x in the below link, https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/guide/saved_model.md